# Playing an artist in iTunes using iMessage and AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes, imessage

So I am goofing around with the 'iTunes Remote Control.applescript' for iMessage to use my phone as a remote control for iTunes.

I am stuck at a point where I would like to send a message with my phone like "Artist Eminem" or any other artist in my library and have it play in iTunes.

This is what I have right now, but I need a string variable to store the part after "Artiest" in, and then have iTunes play that particular string(artist) name.

else if theMessage is "Artiest " then (here I need some sort storing into a string method)

```
 tell app "iTunes"
      play (every track of library playlist 1 whose artist is "<artist stored in string>")
 end tell
```

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
set x to "Artist Bryan Adams"

set y to offset of " " in x
set artist to characters (y + 1) thru -1 in x as string
```

artist is set to "Bryan Adams"

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set mySongs to every track of library playlist 1 whose artist is artist
    play item 1 of mySongs
end tell
```

This will play the first track of that artist. So if you have ordered them according to artist it will play all that artists songs. Not an elegant solution but it's something.